# Executing Remote Powershell Commands using C# or VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm evaluating the best approach to implement the following periodic task:

Get some users from SQL Server (2008) and then for each user enable licences in the Cloud (Office 365) using PowerShell.

My first thought was a console-based app in C# or VB.net but now that I realize that running a PS Script remotely using C# can be quite a challenge I'm starting to think in alternatives like perform all the stuff using PowerShell, I guess this is a better approach but I'd like to hear your thoughts on this.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use SQL Server Shared Management Objects (SMO) to pull in data from SQL server and then handle the Office 365 license enablement once you've got the list of users to iterate over. Alternatively, you can simply use the .NET SQL client to do the data retrieval.

Here's the download of the SQL SMO:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16978

As far as handling the enablement of the Office 365 licenses, it looks like you can use the `Set-MsolUserLicense` cmdlet, which is part of the Office 365 PowerShell cmdlets package.

http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/office365-enterprises/hh125002#BKMK_subs

Answer (score 0):

Well, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C) is how you can do it locally.  ...Add a little Remoting and you're almost there.